# How can i execute C# code in Asp .Net Website

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am new to C# .NET.
I want to know how i can execute a .cs program in an .aspx website buttonClick.

Lets say i want to execute the below code in the buttonclick.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int a = 10;
        int b = 20;
        int c = a + b;

        Console.WriteLine(c);
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}
}
```

And the buttonClick -

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
}
```

Comment: You are welcome to [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/)

Comment: You may choose to export the program as a Nuget package and then call the respective method in your .aspx button event that's one way of doing it.

Comment: Move the code from that Main to your Button1_Click. But you cannot use Console!

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft does not recommend calling an .exe from a Web application as w3wp.exe runs in a sandboxed environment for security reasons and hence any thread/task/process that it launches is not the same as it would be when you launch it yourself and hence may not work as expected.

Is is [possible](http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/ASPNET/334_Working_with_exe_in_ASPNet-Calling_KillingAborting_an_exe.aspx), but not recommended.